# How to group by on two columns and count on the third column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in my postgres table like this.

[image]

I want to get a result like this.

[image: Expected result]

I tried nested query like this. I only did rows where column1 is having multiple values in column2. For example, C3, c4 have just one each, I'd like to skip that.

```
select column1, column2, dCount
from (select column1, column2, count(column3) as dCount
      from schema.table
      where column1 != 0
      group by column1, column2) t
group by t.column1, t.column2, t.dCount
having count(t.column2) > 0;
```

But I am getting 0 rows out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the following two step aggregation query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT column1, column2, COUNT(column3) AS dCount,
           MIN(column2) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) AS min_column2,
           MAX(column2) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) AS max_column2
    FROM schema.table
    WHERE column1 != 0
    GROUP BY column1, column2
)

SELECT column1, column2, dCount
FROM cte
WHERE min_column2 <> max_column2
ORDER BY column1, column2;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! If you don't mind, could you tell me what did that min/max - over do?

Comment: They find the minimum/maximum values of `column2` for each column1 group.  When the min does _not_ equal the max, then there must be more than one column2 value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `group by` and `count()` and `HAVING COUNT(column3) > 1` to get only records with multiple data :

```
SELECT column1, column2, count(column3) as dCount
FROM supportassist.tbldeviceservice
GROUP BY column1, column2
HAVING COUNT(column3) > 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/00-j-0eU)

Comment: The having clause is pointless, as each group must have at least a count of one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am sorry, I edited the question. I am only looking for the rows where first column has multiple values in column 2, and then count the number of values each in column 3.